# Share table column by multiple other tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, ddl

I have a table `TableA` that has column `Active`. I also have `TableB` that has column `Active`. `TableA` and `TableB` have their own PKs. There is FK on `TableB` that points to PK on `TableA`. If record in `TableA` has field `Active` value 0, corresponding records in `TableB` must have `Active` field value set to 0.

A simple way to achieve it would be to create a `DML trigger` that would populate updates in `[TableA].[Active]` field to `[TableB].[Acive]` field.

Is there a way to set `[TableB].[Active]` column so it always references corresponding value of `[TableA].[Active]` column?

Comment: This is why we have normalized databases.  To avoid duplication of data.  Sure, do it in a trigger.  Do it whenever you update Table A.  That doesn't fix the fundamental problem with your database design.

Comment: Basically what @Missy says above. Do you have any reason to keep those data in seperate tables? Cant you combine those tables into 1 table and add an additional attribute as a column that indicates whether the record is TableA type or TableB type. If seperate tables are the way to go though than trigger might indeed be a solution.

Comment: @hchaznedaroglu - Normalization is why I can't combine those tables into 1. There is one-to-many relationship between TableA and TableB. Think of it like a SalesOrderHeader - SalesOrderDetail relationship. If SalesOrderHeader record has Active flag set to 0 then all the SalesOrderDetail records referencing that SOH should have Active flag set to 0 too. If I combined those tables then there would be tons of redundancy.

Comment: @ArtK Oh I see. Then with trigger you can modify your desired column. If you want to ensure this condition before you acutally insert the data, you can try check constraint maybe

Comment: @ArtK Does that mean in table B they could be 0 OR 1?  Like, they are free until their correspondent in table A is 0.